# Empty Array keeps behaving like it has records

Tags: arrays, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-8

I have an `if else block` that returns a list of records if an array has them, and if empty, returns a set of input fields.

I compared two empty arrays,i.e, they both have ZERO records on the database. With my `$jobseeker->exams` array, everything works fine. But with my `$jobseeker->dependents` array, the input fields won't show.

After checking with the rest of the code, I tried to do a `ddd(empty())` check to see if there are any problems with the arrays themselves:

1. `$jobseeker->exams` returned `true` which is expected behavior, when I performed `ddd('$jobseeker->exams')` it returned `null.`
2. `$jobseeker->dependents` returned `false` :/, but when I performed `ddd('$jobseeker->dependents')` after it only shows `[]`. (Again, it currently has NO records on the db)

Things to note:

1. Before this happened, I did have 2 records on my `dependents` table, but I deleted them using PhpMyAdmin. When I thought that this could be the cause, I performed a `migrate:refresh` on my DB, but the result is still the same.
2. The two arrays are two-dimensional arrays where: (this is probably an inaccurate way of describing)

```
$jobseeker->dependents =  [[0]['name','relationship'],[1]['name','relationship']] //and so on
$jobseeker->exams = [[0]['name','date'],[1]['name','date']] //and so on
```

Questions
What happened to my code?
What can I do (if possible):

1. To make my `jobseeker->dependents` array become null again
2. AVoid this from happening again, (how to properly remove records from an eloquent model?)

Answer (score 0):

Check your model, think `dependents` is a relation and laravel call this function and return empty array

refer

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships